# Haskell expand function

Tags: haskell

I was recently handed an assignment I have almost completed and I am currently in need of some help.

The first functions I needed to implement were lookUp, split, combine and keyWordDefs.

I then had to implement a function expand :: FileContents -> FileContents -> FileContents that takes the contents of a text file and an info file and combines them using the above functions to build a string representing the output file.

Here is my code so far:

```
module MP where

import System.Environment

type FileContents = String

type Keyword      = String
type KeywordValue = String
type KeywordDefs  = [(Keyword, KeywordValue)]

separators :: String
separators
  = " \n\t.,:;!\"\'()<>/\\"

lookUp :: String -> [(String, a)] -> [a]
-- Given a search string and a list of string/item pairs, returns
-- the list of items whose associated string matches the search string.
lookUp x y = [a|(b,a) <- y, x==b]

split :: String -> String -> (String, [String])
-- Breaks up a string.
split as [] = ("",[""])
split as (b:bs)
    | elem b as = (b:xs,"":y:ys)
    | otherwise = (xs, (b:y):ys)
         where
          (xs,y:ys) = split as bs

combine :: [Char] -> [String] -> [String]
-- Combines the components of a string from its constituent separator
-- characters and words, as generated by a call to split.
combine [] y = y
combine (x:xs)(y:ys) = y : [x] : combine xs ys

getKeywordDefs :: [String] -> KeywordDefs
-- Takes the contents of an information file in the form of a list
-- of lines and which returns a list of keyword/definition pairs.
getKeywordDefs [] = []
getKeywordDefs (x:xs) = (keyword, concat defs) : getKeywordDefs xs
  where
    (_, (keyword : def)) = split " " x
    defs = combine spaces def
    spaces = [ ' ' | s <- [2..length def]]

expand :: FileContents -> FileContents -> FileContents
```

An example of the function expand is this:

```
expand "The capital of $1 is $2" "$1 Peru\n$2 Lima."
"The capital of Peru is Lima."
```

I suppose that this is going to work by 1st looking up (with function lookUp) if there is a "$" in the input string, then split the words, then replacing words that begin with "$" with the second input string, then combining them again all together? I am really confused actually, and I would like to know if anyone here understand how function expand will work.

Any help is welcome :)

Comment: What is `combine` supposed to do for the input `combine "abc" []`?  You haven't covered all of your cases for pattern matching.

Comment: The point is that when spliting and combining, in the first string there are the separators whereas in the list there are normal strings. So there is no point of an empty list for the second one.

Comment: What do i mean with this is that an example of the function split is this :

split " .," "A comma, then some words."
(" ,
.",["A","comma","","then","some","words",""])

and combine is the opposite. putting the separators in the spaces.

Comment: Just because you don't think it will happen doesn't mean that it won't.  You should always make your functions total.  Another question though: why does `lookUp` return a list?  If multiple values are returned for a single key, what should the behavior of `expand` be?  Should it insert all those values joined together?  Joined together by what?  If it's just supposed to use the first value if it exists, why not use the `Maybe` monad instead and use `Prelude.lookup`?

Comment: lookUp works smth like that:

input: lookUp "A" [("A",8),("B",9),("C",5),("A",7)]
result: [8,7]

Comment: I get that, but what are you supposed to do with multiple values?  What if I had `"The capital of $1 is $2"` and `kws = [("$1", "Brazil"), ("$1", "Peru"), ("$2", "Lima")]`?  Then `lookUp "$1" kws` would return `["Brazil", "Peru"]`, which one gets inserted into the text?

Answer (score 1):

Your expand function should look something like this:

```
-- It's probably better to change the type signature a little bit
-- because we're not returning the contents of a file, we're returning a string.
expand :: FileContents -> FileContents -> String
expand fc1 fc2 = let
    keywordDefs = getKeywordDefs fc2
    in replaceSymbols fc1 keywordDefs
```

Then you need a function named replaceSymbols, which splits up fc1 whenever it sees a $X, and then substitutes that $X for the result of looking up $X in keywordDefs.

```
replaceSymbols :: FileContents  -> KeywordDefs -> String
```

Have a go at implementing that function and reply to this answer if you still need help :).